# How can you configure Rails to use blueprint-css instead of the default scaffolding css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet, scaffolding, blueprint-css

What changes do you need to make to a Rails project to configure blueprintcss as the default stylesheet to be used when you generate scaffolding instead of scaffold.css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend writing your own generator, but if you want to alter the default you can:

1 - For a single app: Freeze rails and change the stylesheet the scaffold generator uses.

railsapp/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails_generators/generators/components/scaffold/templates/style.css

2 - For all apps: Change the same style.css file in your systems rails installation.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute your own scaffolding generation code. Instructions are [here](http://ramblingsonrails.com/how-to-update-the-rails-scaffold-generator-to-suit-your-own-applications) (with the caveat that they may be out of date).

An easier alternative may be to write a Rake action to do textual substitution in the (normally) generated source.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Rails Templates.

You can write one to do much more than replace the css in a rails app.  YOu can make it install gems, freeze rails, all kinds of things.  Take a look at http://youvegotrails.com for an idea of what you can do.